# Vue Simple Table force 2 or 3 columns per cell

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, html-table, vuetify.js

I have the following v-simple table and I am adding v-chip and v-badges to the cells.  I am wondering if there is a way to force a two or three column peer cell column so that they all align accordingly.

Table:
[image]

I have a style scoped only so far.

```
<style scoped>
.time-slot-x-small {
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 1px 3px 1px 5px;
  margin: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
  color: black;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

Comment: are you asking for attrs colspan & rowspan? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: CSS grid can force a specific number of columns. The table cell td could be set to display: grid and set CSS grid to have 2 or 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nested tables inside cells, ie. a `td` can contain a complete table structure including `<table>`, `<tr>`s and `<td>`s